# Display in iframe a div with a certain ID from an external page

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed

I want to display the content of a certain div with the ID="example" from an external page in an iframe on my website, is it possible and how can it be done? I have no control over the external page, only on my website. The only thing i know from that external page is the ID of the div i want to show on my website....maybe you have a fiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilites to build it. (Server or client side).

One of them is use NodeJS working as web crawler, http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/

Here is an example, using NodeJS with express and cheerio (for Jquery manipulation):

```
var url = 'YOUR_URL';

function getContentJSON(body) {
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var content = $('div#ID').text().trim();    
    var result = {"content": content}
    return JSON.stringify(result);
}

function requestPage(url, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var json = getContentJSON(body);
        res.send(statusCodes.OK, json);
      }
    });
}

exports.get = function(request, response) {
    requestPage(url, response);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to display only the div on your website.

As far as I know this is not possible due to browser restrictions. If you just load it into an iframe, you will not be able to manipulate the DOM of the content within that iframe. You could try and see if you can manipulate the scrollbars but I have no knowledge if this is possible or if the same restrictions apply.

Another option would be to load the external page using AJAX. This however will be a cross domain request, requiring the external website to allow CORS requests from your domain. This is highly unlikely. You could use a proxy on your webserver to circumvent this problem.

In short: I don't think this is possible using standard javascript. It could however be done using a server side proxy.